# My intensedebate plug in isn't working on a custom install

Tags: php, javascript, html

Embedded via iWeb because I decided to mock it up quickly.

The buttons and/or functions are not responding at all: http://nomosolo.com/preview/Word_On_The_Street.html

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You have a Javascript error. Make sure the Javascript code is being included into/on the page and that it is valid.